# Two oxidation numbers above one element

Tags: chemistry, mhchem, chemmacros

I'm new to LaTeX and I have a problem.
My code right now is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Bilder/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
% \chemsetup[option]{circled=all}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\userpackage{units}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\chemsetup[redox]{pos=top}
\chemsetup[redox]{align=center}
\chemsetup[redox]{explicit-sign=true}
\chemsetup[redox]{roman=false}
\newcommand{\celsius}{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\parindent0pt
\sloppy
\DeclareChemPhase{\s}{s}
\DeclareChemPhase{\l}{l}
\DeclareChemPhase{\g}{g}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}
\geometry{bottom=60pt} \geometry{top=60pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{\hspace{5pt}}lcr@{\hspace{5pt}}}
    Oxidation:  &  \ce{ 2 \ox{-1,S}\ox{-2,O_3}^2-_{(aq)}  ->  \ox{2.5, S_4}\ox{-2,O_6}^2-_{(aq)}  +  2e^-}  & (39)\\
    Reduktion:  &  \ce{ \ox{0, I_2}_{(aq)} + 2e^-  ->  2 \ox{-1, I}^{-}_{(aq)}}  & (40) \\
    \midrule
    Bilanz:  &  \ce{ 2 \ox{2, S}\ox{-2,O_3}^2-_{(aq)} +\ox{0, I_2}_{(aq)} +  ->   \ox{2.5, S_4}\ox{-2,O_6}^2-_{(aq)} +  2 \ox{-1, I}^{-}_{(aq)}} & (41)
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The thing is that in this molecule sulfur has two oxidation numbers `-1` and `+5`. I now want them both above sulfur but `\ox` doesn't allow that. I tried multiple things and I hope someone has an idea how to solve this please.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Why use both `mhchem` and `chemformula` in one document? Use the `chemmacros` package that also is finetuned to `chemformula` and `chemgreek`.

Comment: A few chemical remarks: in the first sulphite ion you assign a formal charge -1 to the Sulfur ion. But that would give a total charge of -7 on the sulphite ion. The sulphur has a formal charge of +4 to compensate the -6 charge from the three oxygen ions. Also it is not advised to use phases in half reactions, only in the total reaction. You can't assign a phase to the electrons, so you don't assign a phase to all reactants in that half reaction. That is conform the micro representation of those reactions. How do you know the phase of a single reactant?

Comment: When you assign phases to reactants you switch from micro representation to macro representation. Although it is odd, you can do that in the total reaction, stating that mixtures of ions will react with each other. In this case you emphasise that the reaction takes places between solutes of salts containing the reacting ions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: wouldn't it be S2O3 (thiosulfate)?

A quick fix for you would be to write SSO3 and put the oxidation numbers above each of the sulfurs.

But if you want to express the numbers above just one sulfur, I made the code below using chemfig

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    
\schemestart
2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_2\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{3 \, (aq)}} \arrow \chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $+$2.5}}{S}_{4}\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{6 \, (aq)}} \+ 2\chemfig{e^{-}}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart
\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny 0}}{I}_{2 \, (aq)}} \+ 2\chemfig{e^{-}} \arrow 2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1}}{I}^{-}}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\bigskip

\schemestart
2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_2\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{3 \, (aq)}} \+ \chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny 0}}{I}_{2 \, (aq)}} \arrow \chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $+$2.5}}{S}_{4}\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{6 \, (aq)}} \+ 2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1}}{I}^{-}}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Both ideas are great and work. One question: If i want to number the equations how can i do that here. I used \tag before but that doesn't work here

Comment: @Henss -- It is possible to number the reactions using the "amsmath" package and putting each reaction between the commands \begin{align} and \end{align}

Comment: You probably are right, @CrocoDuck . This [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodometry) explains a lot about *iodometry* and states several redox reactions in which iodine/iodide is used to determine the concentration of other reactants, mainly sulphur containing.